# multiplayer game running entirely in browser with server only for db?

Tags: javascript, database, multiplayer, client-side

Is it currently possible / feasible / not crazy to implement a multiplayer game using javascript (+ flash perhaps) with code running entirely in client and a server only used to host a db, which the app/game connects to, to store / get relevant multiplayer information (player&opponents position in game world/items owned/hiscore) ?

Comment: I see problems with using js for the majority of this, the user could manipulate values easily.

Comment: check out [BrowserQuest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/)

Comment: sure you could, but it would be like *me* telling *the bank* how much money I have left after every withdrawal. and stackoverflow isn't the best forum for broad/open-ended questions like this.

Comment: @32bitkit nice way to explain it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no server side code to validate the input received from the clients, the game will be prone to major security issues and everyone will be level 1million in no time.

Server-side code is mostly used to verify user input and format data received by a DB. You cannot do without it.